# Cannot edit and save DLL resources in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2008, resources

I try to open a resource DLL in Visual Studio 2010. The DLL contains a string table with Estonian strings.

I then try to modify one of the string. And then try to save it. But always get an error:

"Cannot save file"

Sometimes, it will ask me to save the file as a new file, then I choose the new file name, but after some more time, the save will still fail.

Sometimes I will see it generate a huge new file.

The original file size is 1.5MB, the new file is 4GB.

Why? I try on VS2010 but also get the same result.